# cards not aligning correctly

Tags: html, css

Im trying to display cards in two columns but the cards are not aligning correctly, the top of the card on the right is displaying at the bottom of the column. id like for the cards to be aligned horizontally by the top of each card

[image: how the cards display]

```css
img {
    width: 269px;
    height: 402px;
}
.card-block{
    margin: 20px;
}

.btn-dark{
    width: 120px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="column-count: 2; margin-top: 100px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-14 mx-auto">
            <div *ngFor="let book of webService.book_list | async">
                <div class="card bg-light mb-5 mr-5" [routerLink]="['/books', book._id]" style="cursor: pointer">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <strong>{{book.title}}</strong> by <strong>{{book.author}}</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row no-gutters">
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <img [src]="book.imageLink" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="card-block">
                                <strong>Country of Origin:</strong> {{book.country}} <br />
                                <strong>Year Released:</strong> {{book.year}} <br />
                                <strong>Language: </strong> {{book?.language}} <br />
                                <strong>Pages: </strong> {{book?.pages}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <strong>{{book.review_count}}</strong>
                        review(s) available <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, perhaps use a flexgrid (or floats) so that the cards flow horizontally?

Comment: Bootstrap's grid system allows up to 12 columns across the page. why r u using col-sm-14 ? maximum is 12 btw

Comment: @BurhamB.Soliman I wasn't aware of this but for some reason col-sm-14 was the only thing allowing the cards to display somewhat correctly, im not exactly sure why this is

Comment: @smarf If more than 12 columns are arranged within a single row, each group of extra columns will considered as one unit, wrap on a new line. So it might be one of your issue's reasons